# html2text library

Tags: c++, html, linux

There is utility html2text in linux. How can i use its or similar library in my c++ code?
For example to convert html which was retrieved from any site to a readable text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for html2text is open and available for free.  Of course, I'd check its license to see if you're allowed to use it in your application.  The source code is [here](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/downloads/).

Comment: You don't need to copy/paste the code; instead, you could compile it separately and link it into your application.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use html2text utility in your code? Like:

```
string output;
output = system('html2text (...)');
```

Maybe it'll resolve your problem.

Comment: :) maybe. but i think that it is not very good method. i'll use it if there will no other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't re-invent the wheel! If html2text's license says you can use its code, do it!